# Getting issue in forcibly fetching an update from Remote Config android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am having issue in force update. below is the sample code I used to fetch force update.

In debug mode(or any lower environment) it will work fine but in release mode I am not getting the update.

Also I checked after 12 hr firebase(remote config) will not sending the force update

```
 final Task<Void> fetch = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(0);
       mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                    .setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds(minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds) //debug = 0 sec, release = 43200 sec
                    .build());
            mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults);
            fetch.addOnSuccessListener(onSuccess -> {......}
```

I assume that it is because of **minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds** value. when I pass 0 in debug mode it will works. but in release I am setting 12hr interval. is that creating issue?

what should be the appropriate value for fetch() and setMinimumFetchIntervalInSeconds()

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve "If configs in the local storage were fetched more than this many seconds ago, configs are served from the backend instead of local storage." Default is 12h and assumes you rarely change the config so that people won't see more than maybe 1 update a day. Local Config is persisted in shared preferences. It would fetch immediately if there is no config present but it will not check for changes anymore within that period.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how your thing is working but what i do is this, i create a node in firebase realtime database and add a observer in my app, when you change the value from firebase console the observer gets called and you can check for the new value and compare it with your previously saved value and show the force update UI.

it like a json :

```
{
"versoin_code": 1
}
```

it is tested and worked seamlessly